# How do I delete read-only file in Gradle?

Tags: file, gradle

How do I delete read-only files in Gradle?
The following code silently ignores read-only files in "C:\Temp" directory:

```
task cleanTempDir(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree(dir: "C:\\Temp")
}
```

Comment: If you could delete the files, they wouldn't be read-only.  Or to turn that around, if you want to be able to delete files, then you must ensure that they are writeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the readonly flag prior to performing the delete.

```
task cleanTempDir << {
    ant.attrib(readonly: false) {
        fileset(dir: 'C:/Temp')
    }
    delete fileTree('C:/Temp')
}
```

This will work on Windows only. If you want this to work on Unix you'll want to use Ant's `chmod` task.

```
ant.chmod(dir: '/tmp', perm: 'ugo+w')
```